# Scala spark Select as not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hope someone can help. Fairly certain this is something I'm doing wrong.

I have a dataframe called uuidvar with 1 column called 'uuid' and another dataframe, df1, with a number of columns, one of which is also 'uuid'. I would like to select from from df1 all of the rows which have a uuid that appear in uuidvar. Now, having the same column names is not ideal so I tried to do it with

```
val uuidselection=df1.join(uuidvar, df1("uuid") === uuidvar("uuid").as("another_uuid"), "right_outer").select("*")
```

However when I show uuidselection I have 2 columns called "uuid". Furthermore, if I try and select the specific columns I want, I am told

```
cannot resolve 'uuidvar' given input columns
```

or similar depending on what I try and select.

I have tried to make it simpler and just do

```
val uuidvar2=uuidvar.select("uuid").as("uuidvar")
```

and this doesn't rename the column in uuidvar.

Does 'as' not operate as I am expecting it to, am I making some other fundamental error or is it broken?

I'm using spark 1.5.1 and scala 1.10.

Comment: You are really using Scala 1.10?

Comment: Thank you. Typo. Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

You can't use `as` when specifying the join-criterion.
Use `withColumnRenamed` to modify the column before the join.
Seccnd, use generic `col` function for accessing columns via name (instead of using the dataframe's `apply` method, e.g. `df1(<columnname>)`

case class UUID1 (uuid: String)
    case class UUID2 (uuid: String, b:Int)

```
class UnsortedTestSuite2 extends SparkFunSuite {
  configuredUnitTest("SO - uuid") { sc =>
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val uuidvar = sc.parallelize( Seq(
      UUID1("cafe-babe-001"),
      UUID1("cafe-babe-002"),
      UUID1("cafe-babe-003"),
      UUID1("cafe-babe-004")
    )).toDF()

    val df1 = sc.parallelize( Seq(
      UUID2("cafe-babe-001", 1),
      UUID2("cafe-babe-002", 2),
      UUID2("cafe-babe-003", 3)
    )).toDF()


    val uuidselection=df1.join(uuidvar.withColumnRenamed("uuid", "another_uuid"), col("uuid") === col("another_uuid"), "right_outer")

    uuidselection.show()
  }
}
```

delivers

```
+-------------+----+-------------+
|         uuid|   b| another_uuid|
+-------------+----+-------------+
|cafe-babe-001|   1|cafe-babe-001|
|cafe-babe-002|   2|cafe-babe-002|
|cafe-babe-003|   3|cafe-babe-003|
|         null|null|cafe-babe-004|
+-------------+----+-------------+
```

## Comment

`.select("*")` does not have any effect. So

```
df.select("*")    =^=        df
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you. If I wanted to go on and filter the result would I need the select or could I just go straight for .filter after that?

Comment: Select is a projection, so you "limit" to specific columns. Having said, you can directly filter on `uuidselection`.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the withColumnRenamed api to rename columns:

Take this table as an example:

| Name | Age |

```
df.withColumnRenamed('Age', 'newAge').show()
```

| Name | newAge |

So to make it work with your code, something like this should work:

```
val uuidvar_another = uuidvar.withColumnRenamed("uuid", "another_uuid")
val uuidselection=df1.join(uuidvar, df1("uuid") === uuidvar("another_uuid"), "right_outer").select("*")
```